# DFS on a graph specified with edges as list of tuples

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

I have a graph with its edges specified as a list of tuples. Say, for example, we have:

```
edges = [('human', 'mammal'), ('mammal', 'vertebrate'), ('mouse', 'mammal'), ('vertebrate', 'animal')]
```

How would we write a method that recursively iterates over all the nodes that can be constructed from the above graph to perform a depth first search traversal in Python?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Constructing a data structure that represents the graph to make traversal easier? Traversing the list of tuples efficiently as the tree it represents? You say you want to perform a DFS, but what exactly would you be querying and what would be the expected result? Have you tried anything yourself and did you get stuck on something specific? Please share your code and some more details.

Comment: There's lots of potential problems as well, that you need to be able to exclude or deal with: can the list of edges have cycles and should you reject such a list? Are there leaf nodes with duplicate values or does every node have a unique value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather fun problem, which you should probably still try to solve yourself, but here's an example of an implementation:

```
from typing import Generator, Union


def construct(edges: list[tuple[str, str]]) -> dict:
    root = {}
    index = {}
    for x, isa in edges:
        if x in root:
            root[isa] = {x: root[x]}
            del root[x]
            index[isa] = root[isa]
        else:
            if x in index:
                raise SyntaxError(f'Invalid tree structure')
            if isa in index:
                index[isa][x] = (d := {})
            else:
                root[isa] = {x: (d := {})}
                index[isa] = root[isa]
            index[x] = d

    return root


def traverse(tree: Union[list[tuple[str, str]], dict]) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    # this assumes that, if tree is a dict, it is a well-constructed tree, as construct() would return it
    if not isinstance(tree, dict):
        tree = construct(tree)

    for node in tree:
        yield node
        yield from traverse(tree[node])


def main():
    edges = [('human', 'mammal'), ('mammal', 'vertebrate'), ('mouse', 'mammal'), ('vertebrate', 'animal')]
    
    for node in traverse(edges):
        print(node)


if __name__  == '__main__':
    main()
```

This constructs a tree in linear time and then traverses it depth-first, yielding the visited nodes. It rejects trees that have duplicate leaf or node values, or cycles.

Output:

```
animal
vertebrate
mammal
human
mouse
```

My recommendation would be you give this example a try, try to understand it, and then write your own from scratch with whatever you learned.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for this. :) Quick question, any reason why you're raising a SyntaxError if the tree structure is invalid?

Comment: You could do any number of things: return an empty dictionary, return `False`, leave the node out and build the rest of the tree, etc. - this seemed like a sensible option because I assumed you wouldn't expect an invalid list of edges to be passed, so an exception is appropriate. However, you need to do *something*, because if you were to just ignore it, the second part of `traverse` would recurse infinitely and crash your script in case a graph with a cycle were to be passed (e.g. `[('mouse', 'mammal'), ('mammal', 'mouse')]`).